# Run function as soon as javascript is linked?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm making a bookmarklet that adds a `<script>` link to a javascript file on my website. Then it will run the function. I can't get it to run, though. `window.onload` doesn't work, as the page has already loaded when the link is added. I'm wondering if there's something that will trigger a function when the javascript is linked.
**New Update:** I found a solution. I used `setTimeout()`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
//code here
}, 0);
```

Putting 0 does seem to work. Thanks for the help, though!

Answer (score 0):

There is not a trigger when javascript is linked, fastest trigger to execute your code is, window.onload will wait load to finish so it's "slower", also see this post may be helpfull
[onload vs ready](http://Also%20see%20this%20post%20may%20be%20helpful%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Comment: Do you think void function() {//script here}; would work? This function is just a series of if...then statements that trigger other functions. It doesn't have to return anything. Also, I'm kinda new to the void operator, so I might be using it wrong. Also, I'd love to upvote your post, but I can't because I'm new here.

Comment: In javascript you don't need to put void function, functions can return a value or not you don't need to necessary type it.